# ng-change on a input[type=time]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

The ng-change directive on a input field with type time only fires once, it isn't fired on subsequent changes. I could argue that this is because the object reference itself (Date object) doesn't change anymore. Does anyone know a way in which i can make the ng-change directive to work in this scenario.

Im using chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit), and angularjs version 1.3.15

Comment: What browser and angular version are you using?

Comment: Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) and angularjs version 1.3.15

Comment: This plunk should work for you. I'm also using Chrome. http://plnkr.co/edit/2IlZow1BxJtgWFqTqhnw?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6aiWfbv5XzGwGKellGQv?p=preview I a fork of this plunk and changed the type to time, you'll notice that it doesn't work anymore in that scenario

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the ngChange is not firing because Angular is throwing a NaN so the event is never fired (if that is the case).

According to the AngularJS documentation, if the browser does not support the date type field it will consider it a text type field.  However, the data MUST be a valid DATE object. I would recommend writing a validator for that field to ensure the data entered is an actual date object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Comment: I checked it is a date object, and the first change it works but subsequent changes don't work

Comment: The first change is _detected_ but the actual date object is blanked out. So the model is missing and that's probably why subsequent changes aren't detected. I would write a validator to keep the model a date object like @C Sigmon said

Comment: I created a validator, but it still doesn't fire on subsequent changes this while the modelValue is a date object. I have updated the plunk. Am i forgetting something? http://plnkr.co/edit/6aiWfbv5XzGwGKellGQv?p=preview

Comment: Change your field type to date and not time. If you will notice it is not validating thus, it is not firing ngChange.

Comment: If you will notice it is not validating thus, it is not firing ngChange. In your example, you are requesting the user to chose a date in 2013, but only giving them time options.
      
Here is your Plunk forked http://plnkr.co/edit/fzqG0LkHEZl2Ugqev7Og?p=preview